# CMake: Function is callable while script, defined it, is no longer included

Tags: cmake

I have three folders in a location, say A,B and C. I have two cmake files in folder A: `FindABC.cmake` and `UseABC.cmake`. The former is for finding the libraries and the latter contains a function, say run_command(). `CMakelists.txt` in folder B and folder C contains the following lines:

```
find_package(ABC)
include(UseABC)
run_command()
```

It works as intended. Now If I comment `find_package()` and `include()` in `CMakelists` of folder C, as far as I know, Cmake should give an error telling `unknown command - run_command()`. But, the controls goes into the function and executes in unpredictable manner.

How come the control goes to the function when the include line is commented? The root `CMakelists` that lists the sub-directories does not have any `find_package` or `include` lines in it.

Edit:

UseABC.cmake:

```
set(ABC_COMPILE_DEBUG FALSE)
set(ABC_COMPILE_OUTPUT_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/abc_gen")
message("USEABC1 - -> " ${ABC_COMPILE_OUTPUT_DIR})
function(run_command)
    message("USEABC2 - File recurs -> " ${ABC_COMPILE_OUTPUT_DIR})
    file(REMOVE_RECURSE "${ABC_COMPILE_OUTPUT_DIR}")
    file(MAKE_DIRECTORY "${ABC_COMPILE_OUTPUT_DIR}")
    add_custom_command() #command to be executed
endfunction()
```

Here, When nothing is commented(find_package and include is not commented in any CMakelists.txt), I get the correct path for the two messages I print.

When I comment `include(UseABC)` in the second `CMakelists.txt`, the configuration fails, the first message is not at all printed and the second message gets printed, but does not give the value of the variable. It also deletes all the files in Folder C (but the argument to `REMOVE_RECURSE` is empty).

Comment: Please provide a minimal example, explain what you expect and what you actually get. BTW, have you always cleared your cache?

Comment: @usr1234567: Example provided. I cleared the cache. What I require is, the control should not be passed to the function when include(UseABC)is commented

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I correctly understand the situation, you have:

**CMakeLists.txt**:

```
add_subdirectory(B)
add_subdirectory(C)
```

**B/CMakeLists.txt**:

```
find_package(ABC)
include(UseABC)
```

In that case `run_command` function, defined in `UseABC.cmake`, is *accessible* in `C/CMakeLists.txt`, though this script doesn't define it.

In CMake **function definitions are global**.

---

By opposite, **variable definitions are local** to the scope, where they are defined. (Until variables are *cached* ones, in that case they have global visibility).

That is, variable *ABC_COMPILE_DEBUG* defined in `UseABC.cmake` is **accessible** in

- `UseABC.cmake` script
- `B/CMakeLists.txt` script, because it includes `UseABC.cmake` one, and `include()` command *doesn't* introduce a *scope*

but it is **inaccessible** in

- `CMakeLists.txt` script, because `add_subdirectory(B)` *does* introduce a *scope*
- `C/CMakeLists.txt` script

More details about variable's visibility can be found in [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/manual/cmake-language.7.html#cmake-language-variables).

Comment: If that is the case, why doesn't the `SET` statements written before function in `UseABC.cmake` gets executed? Is the only solution is to move the `SET` statements into the function body?

Comment: As opposite to `function()` command, which effect is **global**, effect of `set()` command in script `UseABS.cmake` is **local** to the scope of includer (`B/CMakeLists.txt`). See updated answer. Yes, you may call `set()` from the *function body*, so it will be in effect when the function is called from `C/CMakeLists.txt`. Alternatively, you may create *cached* variable: `set(ABC_COMPILE_DEBUG FALSE CACHE INTERNAL "")`. Such variable will have global visibility.